# How to make slide menu to middle left side of the screen in android

Tags: android, xml, slider

[image]

Here,In The above image ,check the marked red circle.The marked red circle represents Sliding menu.I need to show the sliding menu as like in the image(middle left of the screen).

When clicking on the red circle image,it should slides or expand the
view.please help me over this

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Bringing a dinosaur back to life!

Comment: @Preethi Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083774/how-to-add-dragable-icon-with-navigation-drawer/35252280#35252280