# How to add draggable icon with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

**My problem:**

I want to add draggable icon in navigation drawer.

This icon combined with listview of navigation drawer when drawer open.

see similar like this,

[image]

**What I have tried,**

I searched in StackOverflow like similar question this,

[Draggable drawer with a handle (instead of action bar) on top of other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768360/draggable-drawer-with-a-handle-instead-of-action-bar-on-top-of-other-apps)

But all answer suggest to 3rd party library.

**My question**

1.It`s possible to add draggable icon with navigation drawer?

Comment: I want similar dragable navigation drawer only..not coc:)

Comment: As far as I can tell looking at the DrawerLayout source code it cannot behave exactly as you want it to. (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java) So either you have to use a library, or you should subclass DrawerLayout and create your own ViewDragHelper that behaves like you want it to behave. (to understand the principle, look here:http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/)

Comment: really thanks @jmols.. I will try this.

Comment: Good luck with that! Let me know if you can get it to work.

Comment: Do you want just that icon to be there instead of the default hamburger icon? And on click of that you open and close the drawer ?

Comment: @mike20132013 yes..But icon combine with drawer open & close.

Comment: You can toggle the on and off of drawer with that icon placed there using toolbar as ur top bar and adding a custom view as ur toolbar layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `drag layout` there is **github library** which is useful for it
You can drag from left to right or any where. It will also slide from left to right & also drag is also possible.[Drag Layout link](https://github.com/kedzie/DraggableDrawers)

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/left_big_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FFFF">
        <TextView android:text="LEFT"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@id/left_big_handle"
               android:background="@drawable/handle"
               android:layout_gravity="top"
               android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
               android:layout_width="24dp"
               android:layout_height="80dp"/>
</com.kedzie.drawer.DraggedDrawer>
```

> handle.xml drawable file of handle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/status_bar_close_red" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/status_bar_close_off" />

</selector>
```

> ScreenShot

[image]

Hope this is useFul for you.

Comment: glad to help you @Ranjith